# javascript how to loop and get the first satisfied condition object with the respective index and parent index

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Here is my data set object set, i want to iterate and need the result of below noted item:

```
var data = [
    { 
        name: 'sam', 
        id: 12235,
        qccheck: { hit: false},
        company: [
                   {
                      name: 'comp1' , 
                      Id: 5356,
                      qccheck: { hit: false},
                   },
                   {
                      name: 'comp2' , 
                      Id: 7645,
                      qccheck: { hit: true},
                   }
                ]
   },
   { 
        name: 'mark', 
        id: 8877,
        qccheck: { hit: true},
        company: [
                   {
                      name: 'comp3', 
                      Id: 3865,
                      qccheck: { hit: true},
                   },
                   {
                      name: 'comp4', 
                      Id: 87546,
                      qccheck: { hit: false},
                   }
                ]
   }
]
```

i) first condition `('qccheck: { hit: true}')` satisfied object item.
   i.e: the result should be

```
  {
      name: 'comp2' , 
      Id: 7645,
      qccheck: { hit: true},
   }
```

ii) and the index of both condition satisfied object and the parent object
    i.e: the result should be `'data index = 0'` and child `'company index=1'

so basically after iteration of the loop i want to know the first condition satisfied object and the index of that object as well as the parent object index

can anyone suggest the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Post the code that you attempted!

Comment: please add the wanted result along the code, you tried.

Comment: Nina: wanted result i already stated... need the first condition satisfied object along with that index and its respective parent index...

Comment: @Krish have you tried anything ?

Comment: Please avoid posting multiple requirements

Comment: prerak: i just recreated the data structure to post this question, the attempted code its not in hand at this moment, but i tried with for in loop to break when conditions satisfied.. i want the best approach to take it further..

Comment: the problem is, you have multiple `hit` with `true`. which qualifies for the result? and how should look the result.

Comment: Nina: i want the first object which is having hit. in the order of parent then child, i.e data name sam  then company array object wise... that is if the parent is not hit true but the child is having hit true. i want that child object.. also the index of both child and parent.

Comment: Post the code that you attempted with the issues in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple double `for` loop should do the trick

```
var obj = null;
var data_index = -1;
var company_index = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
{
  if (data[i].qccheck.hit)
  {
    obj = data[i];
    data_index = i;
    break;
  }

  if (!data[i].company) continue;
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].company.length; ++j)
  {
    if (data[i].company[j].qccheck.hit)
    {
      obj = data[i].company[j];
      data_index = i;
      company_index = j;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (obj) break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want.

### ES5

```js
var data = [{ name: 'sam', id: 12235, qccheck: { hit: false }, company: [{ name: 'comp1', Id: 5356, qccheck: { hit: false } }, { name: 'comp2', Id: 7645, qccheck: { hit: true } }] }, { name: 'mark', id: 8877, qccheck: { hit: true }, company: [{ name: 'comp3', Id: 3865, qccheck: { hit: true } }, { name: 'comp4', Id: 87546, qccheck: { hit: false } }] }],
    result;

data.some(function (object, i) {
    if (object.qccheck.hit) {
        return result = { object: object, dataIndex: i };
    }
    return object.company.some(function (company, j) {
        if (company.qccheck.hit) {
            return result = { company: company, dataIndex: i, companyIndex: j };
        }
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

### ES6

```js
var data = [{ name: 'sam', id: 12235, qccheck: { hit: false }, company: [{ name: 'comp1', Id: 5356, qccheck: { hit: false } }, { name: 'comp2', Id: 7645, qccheck: { hit: true } }] }, { name: 'mark', id: 8877, qccheck: { hit: true }, company: [{ name: 'comp3', Id: 3865, qccheck: { hit: true } }, { name: 'comp4', Id: 87546, qccheck: { hit: false } }] }],
    result;

data.some((object, dataIndex) =>
    object.qccheck.hit && (result = { object, dataIndex }) ||
    object.company.some((company, companyIndex) => 
        company.qccheck.hit && (result = { company, dataIndex, companyIndex }))
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this (ES5):

```js
var data = [{ name: 'sam', id: 12235, qccheck: { hit: false }, company: [{ name: 'comp1', Id: 5356, qccheck: { hit: false } }, { name: 'comp2', Id: 7645, qccheck: { hit: true } }] }, { name: 'mark', id: 8877, qccheck: { hit: true }, company: [{ name: 'comp3', Id: 3865, qccheck: { hit: true } }, { name: 'comp4', Id: 87546, qccheck: { hit: false } }] }];

let company, dataIndex, companyIndex;

data.some(function(a, i) {
  dataIndex = i;
  return a.company.some(function(b, j) {
    companyIndex = j;
    company = b;
    return b.qccheck.hit
  })
})

console.log(company)
console.log(dataIndex, companyIndex)
```

`some` will stop the loop once a matching `company` is found.

Here's an ES6 one-liner:

```js
let data = [{ name: 'sam', id: 12235, qccheck: { hit: false }, company: [{ name: 'comp1', Id: 5356, qccheck: { hit: false } }, { name: 'comp2', Id: 7645, qccheck: { hit: true } }] }, { name: 'mark', id: 8877, qccheck: { hit: true }, company: [{ name: 'comp3', Id: 3865, qccheck: { hit: true } }, { name: 'comp4', Id: 87546, qccheck: { hit: false } }] }];

let output;

data.some((a, i) => a.company.some((b, j) => 
    output = b.qccheck.hit && { company: b, dataIndex: i, companyIndex: j }))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: BTW, `find` is ES6.

Comment: @NinaScholz dammit. Will use a nested `some` then

Comment: adiga: sorry one more clarification, if the parent object hit is true i want the whole parent object, if hit is false and the child(company) is true then only i want only the company. please note below the updates in the object set.

Comment: { 
        name: 'mark', 
        id: 8877,
        qccheck: { hit: true},
        company: [
                   {
                      name: 'comp3', 
                      Id: 3865,
                      qccheck: { hit: true},
                   },
                   {
                      name: 'comp4', 
                      Id: 87546,
                      qccheck: { hit: false},
                   }
    ]
   }

Comment: please add additional information to the question and not in comments!

Comment: i.e if the parent object is true i want the whole object in result. else i want to look in to the respective child.

Comment: @adinga: if matching company is not found both parent and child I’m getting returns value as undefined.. is that any other way to get as flag or variable as companyNotFound or notFound: true like this? So that I can use my other logic??